# Electron Notification Buttons

Tags: notifications, electron

I've just started playing around with Electron some and was wondering if there is a way to add buttons or other elements to notifications? My company might use Electron to build a product and it would be awesome if we could have answer/hangup buttons or a quick reply text box and button right on the notification. Is this possible within Electron?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use electron-tray notifications and add menu options to tray for calling specific events:  https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/tray.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Electron [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration/#notifications-windows-linux-os-x) you can see:

> Electron conveniently allows developers to send notifications with the HTML5 Notification API, using the currently running operating system's native notification APIs to display it.

So, I suppose it offers only options [defined in the API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/).